# Opening a link in the same modal window

Tags: javascript, html

I open a modal window which loads a page.html from main.html page. In page.html I have a link to page2.html.

The link on page 2 opens the page2 in a new modal windows. I want it to open in the same window.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Like Joseph said use:

```
<a href="http://example.com" target="_self">Link</a>
```